# Web2Py and MySQL at PythonAnywhere is much slower than locally

Tags: mysql, web2py, pythonanywhere

My app is Web2Py on MySQL and consists mostly of queries and simple display of textual results. No images, videos or fancy CSS.

Locally, queries response time is sub second.
Deployed to PythonAnywhere (using the couple of basic efficiency tricks in the Web2Py book) - and the same queries may take 7-8 seconds each !
PA support mentioned that inefficiencies in my code, which are not evident locally may become an issue on the network.
Ok...what kind of inefficiencies should I look for ?

Massimo's thougths:

> One possibility is that on your local machine the database and the
>   server run on the same machine. On pythonanywhere (and most hosting)
>   they may run on different machines therefore you have network latency.
>   Moreover I do not know if the mysql instance if dedicated or shared
>   between many users.

Any ideas how I can improve the performance when hosted at PythonAnywhere ? 
Anybody experienced similar issues ?

Comment: This is the one reason why my development database server runs on a sheevaplug (1.2Ghz on 512MB ram) using a NAS for storage. All timely queries and every query added will result in (significant) slowdown. It's oldskool, but works perfectly.

Also, using [db._timings](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Timing-queries) which is easily exposed when using `{{=response.toolbar()}}` helps a lot to find repetitive and slow queries.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities that come to mind here -- the first is that it was the result of a slow database server on PythonAnywhere the other day (see [this forum thread](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/2087/), perhaps that was you posting there too?)

The second is that it might be a latency thing.  Sites that make a lot of requests per page can run significantly slower once you put them onto a remote host.  Browsers will normally make about ten parallel requests at a time, so a page that loads (say) twenty CSS files, JavaScript files, or images will take at least double the round-trip time from client to server to load.  30 files, three times, and so on.  Once you've added processing time on both client and server to that, things can be quite slow.

Comment: The OP mentioned that the site in question has text-based pages with few extra assets.